# Download All Files From a Folder on a Website

Tags: r, download

My question is in R how to download all the files on a website? I know how to do it one by one but not all at one time. For example:

http://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/maps-data/data/rel/t00t10/

Answer (score 13):

I tested this on a small subset (3) of the 56 files on the page, and it works fine.

```
## your base url
url <- "http://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/maps-data/data/rel/t00t10/"
## query the url to get all the file names ending in '.zip'
zips <- XML::getHTMLLinks(
    url, 
    xpQuery = "//a/@href['.zip'=substring(., string-length(.) - 3)]"
)
## create a new directory 'myzips' to hold the downloads
dir.create("myzips")
## save the current directory path for later
wd <- getwd()
## change working directory for the download
setwd("myzips")
## create all the new files
file.create(zips)
## download them all
lapply(paste0(url, zips), function(x) download.file(x, basename(x)))
## reset working directory to original
setwd(wd)
```

Now all the zip files are in the directory `myzips` and are ready for further processing.  As an alternative to `lapply()` you could also use a `for()` loop.

```
## download them all
for(u in paste0(url, zips)) download.file(u, basename(u))
```

And of course, setting `quiet = TRUE` may be nice since we're downloading 56 files.

Comment: This works well.  However, for a site I used it on, `zips` contained the full path to the zip files.  Therefore, the `paste0(url, zips)` was unnecessary in the `lapply` function, `zips` was sufficient.  Thanks @Dirty Sock Sniffer.

Comment: @Rich is there a way not to overwrite files?

Comment: @Rich Scriven Thanks for your response, but what is the meaning of   xpQuery = "//a/@href['.txt'=substring(., string-length(.) - 3)]"
and how can I changed for text files?

Answer (score 9):

Slightly different approach.

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(pbapply)
library(stringi)

URL <- "http://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/maps-data/data/rel/t00t10/"

pg <- read_html(URL)
zips <- grep("zip$", html_attr(html_nodes(pg, "a[href^='TAB']"), "href"), value=TRUE)

invisible(pbsapply(zips, function(zip_file) {
  GET(URL %s+% zip_file, write_disk(zip_file))
}))
```

You get a progress bar with this and built-in "caching" (`write_disk` won't overwrite already downloaded files).

You can weave in Richard's excellent code for dir creation & file checking as well.

Comment: What does `a[href^='TAB']` do? That looks neat.

Comment: It chooses all links that have `href` elements that start with `TAB`

Comment: So good to know! I was trying to use links[grep("TAB2000", links)] to subset the list of href attributes but using grep felt very unintuitive.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks for the response but what is the meaning of "a[href^='TAB']" and how can I change it to download txt files?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use python 3, I just managed to make this code work for a similar census website. It is not that cool because I had to hard-code all the state codes, but it does the job:

```
import wget
root_url = 'https://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/maps-data/data/rel/t00t10/TAB2000_TAB2010_ST_'
states = [str(st) for st in ["01","02","04","05", "06", "08", "09","10", 
                         "11", "12", "13", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
                         "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
                         "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33","34",
                        "35","36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42",
                        "44", "45","46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51",
                        "53", "54", "55", "56", "72"]]
ext = '_v2.zip'
for state in states:
    print("downloading state number " + state)
    fname = state + ext
    wget.download(root_url + fname)
```