# Download all files on a webpage with R?

Tags: r, xml, download

My question is almost same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790052/download-all-files-from-a-folder-on-a-website). I want to download all files from [this page](http://dwtkns.com/srtm/). But the difference is I do not have the same pattern to be able to download all the files.

Any idea to get the download in R ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# use the FTP mirror link provided on the page
mirror <- "ftp://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SRTM_v41/SRTM_Data_GeoTIFF/"

# read the file listing
pg <- readLines(mirror)

# take a look
head(pg)
## [1] "06-18-09  06:18AM               713075 srtm_01_02.zip"
## [2] "06-18-09  06:18AM               130923 srtm_01_07.zip"
## [3] "06-18-09  06:18AM               130196 srtm_01_12.zip"
## [4] "06-18-09  06:18AM               156642 srtm_01_15.zip"
## [5] "06-18-09  06:18AM               317244 srtm_01_16.zip"
## [6] "06-18-09  06:18AM               160847 srtm_01_17.zip"

# clean it up and make them URLs
fils <- sprintf("%s%s", mirror, sub("^.*srtm", "srtm", pg))

head(fils)
## [1] "ftp://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SRTM_v41/SRTM_Data_GeoTIFF/srtm_01_02.zip"
## [2] "ftp://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SRTM_v41/SRTM_Data_GeoTIFF/srtm_01_07.zip"
## [3] "ftp://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SRTM_v41/SRTM_Data_GeoTIFF/srtm_01_12.zip"
## [4] "ftp://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SRTM_v41/SRTM_Data_GeoTIFF/srtm_01_15.zip"
## [5] "ftp://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SRTM_v41/SRTM_Data_GeoTIFF/srtm_01_16.zip"
## [6] "ftp://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SRTM_v41/SRTM_Data_GeoTIFF/srtm_01_17.zip"

# test download
download.file(fils[1], basename(fils[1]))

# validate it worked before slamming the server (your job)

# do the rest whilst being kind to the mirror server
for (f in fils[-1]) {
  download.file(f, basename(f))
  Sys.sleep(5) # unless you have entitlement issues, space out the downloads by a few seconds
}
```

If you don't mind using a non-base package, `curl` can help you just get the file names vs doing the `sub` above:

```
unlist(strsplit(rawToChar(curl::curl_fetch_memory(mirror, curl::new_handle(dirlistonly=TRUE))$content), "\n"))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the most elegant solution, but it appears to be working when I try it on random subsets of `helplinks`.

```
library(rvest)

#Grab filenames from separate URL
helplinks <- read_html("http://rdf.muninn-project.org/api/elevation/datasets/srtm/") %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_text(trim = T)

#Keep only filenames relevant for download
helplinks <- helplinks[grepl("srtm", helplinks)]

#Download files - make sure to adjust the `destfile` argument of the download.file function.
lapply(helplinks, function(x) download.file(sprintf("http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SRT-ZIP/SRTM_V41/SRTM_Data_GeoTiff/%s", x), sprintf("C:/Users/aud/Desktop/%s", x)))
```