# Downloading txt files from multiple directories using R

Tags: r, function, download, txt

I've been trying to download .txt files from https://ds.data.jma.go.jp/gmd/goos/data/pub/JMA-product/cobe2_sst_glb_M/

So far, I've managed to download the complete set for 1850 by using the code from [Download all the files (.zip and .txt) from a webpage using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70987871/download-all-the-files-zip-and-txt-from-a-webpage-using-r) which is, for my case:

```
page <- "https://ds.data.jma.go.jp/gmd/goos/data/pub/JMA-product/cobe2_sst_glb_M/1850/"

a <- readLines(
  page
  )

loc.txt <- grep(
  ".txt",
  a
  )

#------------------------------------
convfn <- function(line, marker, page){
  i <- unlist(gregexpr(pattern ='href="', line)) + 6
  i2<- unlist(gregexpr(pattern =,marker,  line)) + 3
  #target file
  .destfile <- substring(line, i[1], i2[1])
  #target url
  .url      <- paste(page, .destfile, sep = "/")
  #print targets
  cat(.url, '\n', .destfile, '\n')
  #the workhorse function
  download.file(url=.url, destfile=.destfile)
}
#------------------------------------

print(
  getwd()
  )

sapply(a[loc.txt], 
       FUN = convfn, 
       marker = '.txt"',
       page = page)
```

I would like to know how to write a function that will allow me to automate replacing the years 1850 to 2022 since doing this would somehow be long and repetitive (over 170 years). My idea is somehow stuck on the line:

```
page <- paste0("https://ds.data.jma.go.jp/gmd/goos/data/pub/JMA-product/cobe2_sst_glb_M/", c(seq(1850, 2022, by = 1)), "/")
```

but I do not know how to make it into a working function

Please help, thank you and keep safe

Best regards,
Raven

Comment: what about putting all codes in a for loop? This will work with iterating over the years and making new pages in each iteration round; however, you may modify your code a bit to avoid the result being overwritten in each round of iteration. 
`for(y in 1850:2022){
  page <- paste0("https://ds.data.jma.go.jp/gmd/goos/data/pub/JMA-product/cobe2_sst_glb_M/",y,"/")
  print(page)
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to do this differently. Better to use xml/xpath to extract the file links.

```
library(httr)   # for GET(...)
library(XML)    # for htmlParse(...)
base.url <- 'https://ds.data.jma.go.jp/gmd/goos/data/pub/JMA-product/cobe2_sst_glb_M'
get.docs <- function(year) {
  url  <- paste(base.url, year, sep='/')
  html <- htmlParse(content(GET(url), type='text'))
  file.names <- html['//td/a/@href'][-1]   # first href is to parent directory; remove
  ##
  # uncomment next line to save files
  #
  # mapply(download.file, paste(url, file.names, sep='/'), file.names)
  print(sprintf('Downloaded from: %s to: %s', paste(url, file.names, sep='/'), file.names))
}
lapply(1850:2022, get.docs)
```

Comment: thank you, I am more willing to try this out