# R: import multiple files from online source

Tags: r, xml, lapply

I have 5 years of day-by-day weather files called "CUSTOM-ARC-***date***-METRIC.csv", here (https://sci.ncas.ac.uk/leedsweather/Archive/). Is there a way of importing them all into one big file in R?

I'm trying this code ([based on this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790052/download-all-files-from-a-folder-on-a-website)) but i'm getting an error saying the content is not XML. Any thoughts around this? Also I'm only interested in the ***-METRIC*** files.

```
url <- "https://sci.ncas.ac.uk/leedsweather/Archive/"
## query the url to get all the file names ending in '.csv'
weatherFiles <- XML::getHTMLLinks(
  url, 
  xpQuery = "//a/@href['.csv'=substring(., string-length(.) - 3)]"
)
## create a new directory 'weather' to hold the downloads
dir.create("weather")
## save the current directory path for later
wd <- getwd()
## change working directory for the download
setwd("weather")
## create all the new files
file.create(weatherFiles)
## download them all
lapply(paste0(url, weatherFiles), function(x) download.file(x, basename(x)))
## reset working directory to original
setwd(wd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider XML's `htmlParse` using `readLines` on *url* and run same XPath expression. Below processes first 5 CSVs using index `[1:5]` in `lapply` (*weatherFiles* has a length of 3,344).

```
url <- "https://sci.ncas.ac.uk/leedsweather/Archive/"    
doc <- htmlParse(readLines(url))

## query the url to get all the file names ending in '.csv'
weatherFiles <- XML::xpathSApply(doc, path="//a/@href['.csv'=substring(., string-length(.) - 3)]")

df_list <- lapply(weatherFiles[1:5], function(f) {
  # DOWNLOAD FILE LOCALLY USING *wb* MODE
  download.file(paste0(url, f), paste0(getwd(), "/", f), mode="wb")

  # IMPORT WITH TRYCATCH FOR PROBLEMATIC CSVS
  tryCatch(read.csv(paste0("weather_", f), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), error = function(e) NULL)      
})

# REMOVE NULLS
df_list <- Filter(function(x) !is.null(x), df_list)

# CLEAN UP NAMES (MAY NEED TO ADD)
df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(df) {
  clean_names <- gsub("Winddir", "WindDir", gsub("\\.", "", gsub("\\.\\.\\..*$", "", names(df))))
  setNames(df, clean_names)
})

# DATA FRAME APPEND
# final_df <- base::do.call(rbind, df_list)             # FAILS IF COLUMN NUMBER AND NAMES DO NOT MATCH
final_df  <- plyr::ldply(unname(df_list), data.frame)
final_df  <- dplyr::bind_rows(df_list)
```

**Output** *(first 5 CSVs)*

*structure*

```
str(final_df)
'data.frame':   1152 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ Timestamp   : chr  "2018-07-15 00:00:00" "2018-07-15 00:05:00" "2018-07-15 00:10:00" "2018-07-15 00:15:00" ...
 $ Temp        : num  64 63.9 63.7 63.5 63.4 ...
 $ Chill       : num  64 63.9 63.7 63.5 63.4 ...
 $ HIndex      : num  64 63.9 63.7 63.5 63.4 ...
 $ Humid       : num  75 75 75.8 76 76.2 ...
 $ Dewpt       : num  55.9 55.8 55.9 55.8 55.8 ...
 $ Wind        : num  2.09 1.6 2.66 2.62 2.68 ...
 $ HiWind      : num  5 5 5 6 6 5 5 5 5 6 ...
 $ WindDir     : num  293 312 305 310 325 ...
 $ Rain        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ RainRate    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Barom       : num  29.7 29.7 29.7 29.7 29.7 ...
 $ Solar       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ET          : num  0.000254 0.000253 0.000248 0.000243 0.000238 ...
 $ UV          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ InsideTemp  : num  75.6 75.6 75.6 75.6 75.6 ...
 $ InsideHumid : num  46.8 47 47 47 47 ...
 $ TimestampUTC: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Pressure    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Radiation   : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

*rows*

```
head(final_df)

            Timestamp     Temp    Chill   HIndex    Humid    Dewpt     Wind HiWind  WindDir Rain RainRate    Barom
1 2018-07-15 00:00:00 63.99530 63.99530 63.99530 75.00000 55.90705 2.087248      5 292.7708    0        0 29.72160
2 2018-07-15 00:05:00 63.85101 63.85101 63.85101 75.00000 55.76779 1.597315      5 312.1093    0        0 29.72003
3 2018-07-15 00:10:00 63.71074 63.71074 63.71074 75.77852 55.91708 2.657718      5 304.5494    0        0 29.71821
4 2018-07-15 00:15:00 63.54564 63.54564 63.54564 76.00000 55.83850 2.617450      6 309.9667    0        0 29.71859
5 2018-07-15 00:20:00 63.38658 63.38658 63.38658 76.21477 55.76223 2.684564      6 324.8235    0        0 29.71940
6 2018-07-15 00:25:00 63.25800 63.25800 63.25800 77.00000 55.92122 2.206667      5 325.4155    0        0 29.71861
  Solar           ET UV InsideTemp InsideHumid TimestampUTC Pressure Radiation
1     0 0.0002544508  0       75.6    46.79866         <NA>       NA        NA
2     0 0.0002525977  0       75.6    47.00000         <NA>       NA        NA
3     0 0.0002480646  0       75.6    47.00000         <NA>       NA        NA
4     0 0.0002431687  0       75.6    47.00000         <NA>       NA        NA
5     0 0.0002382909  0       75.6    47.00000         <NA>       NA        NA
6     0 0.0002372467  0       75.6    47.00000         <NA>       NA        NA
```

Comment: I'd like to accept your answer (I don't know why i didn't do it at the time). Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised no one has answered this question before now.  Well, I like things like this, so I took a stab at it.  This is what I came up with.  Change the script to suit your needs (i.e., start_date and end_date...I just entered a very small range of dates to test the functionality).

```
mydownload <- function (start_date, end_date) {
  start_date <- as.Date(start_date)  ## convert to Date object
  end_date <- as.Date(end_date)  ## convert to Date object
  dates <- as.Date("1970/01/01") + (start_date : end_date)  ## date sequence
  ## a loop to download data
  for (i in 1:length(dates)) {
    string_date <- as.character(dates[i])
    myfile <- paste0("C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/weather/", string_date, ".csv")
    string_date <- gsub("-", "-", string_date)  ## replace "-" with "/"
    myurl <- paste("https://sci.ncas.ac.uk/leedsweather/Archive/CUSTOM-ARC-", string_date, "-METRIC.csv", sep = "")
    download.file(url = myurl, destfile = myfile, quiet = TRUE)
    }
  }

mydownload("2013/11/25", "2013/11/30")
```