# Download all the txt files from a website

Tags: r, file, url, text, download

I would like to download multiple text files which ends with .txt from a website. I am trying to use these answers [Download All Files From a Folder on a Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790052/download-all-files-from-a-folder-on-a-website)

So I changed the answers to txt ending files but none of the solutions from this page worked for me. I think I have to change this line of the first answer

```
  xpQuery = "//a/@href['.txt'=substring(., string-length(.) - 3)]"
```

for txt files but I don't know how.

The edited code is something like below:

```
## your base url
url <- "https://..."
## query the url to get all the file names ending in '.txt'
txts <- XML::getHTMLLinks(
  url, 
  xpQuery = "//a/@href['.txt'=substring(., string-length(.) - 3)]"
)
## create a new directory 'mytxts' to hold the downloads
dir.create("mytxts")
## save the current directory path for later
wd <- getwd()
## change working directory for the download
setwd("mytxts")
## create all the new files
file.create(txts)
## download them all
lapply(paste0(url, txts), function(x) download.file(x, basename(x)))
## reset working directory to original
setwd(wd)
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what is not working?  Are you able to generate a list of files with `XML::getHTMLLinks(...)`?

Comment: No zero characters

Comment: @Dave2e So I think   xpQuery = "//a/@href['.zip'=substring(., string-length(.) - 3)]"
is written for zip files but I have to change it for txt files and I don't  know how