# Download all files in all folders from URL

Tags: r, curl, rvest, rselenium, rcurl

I'd like to recursively download all files from nested folders from this URL to my computer in the same nested structure:

`https://hazardsdata.geoplatform.gov/?prefix=Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE/South_Dakota/60601300_BrookingsCO/Brookings%20HYDA/`

I've tried several different approaches, using `curl` and `RCurl`, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790052/download-all-files-from-a-folder-on-a-website) and some others. There are multiple file types within this folder. But I keep running into cryptic error message such as `Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :  error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version`

I'm not even sure how to begin.

Comment: You may need `RSelenium` to download the files. `remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>%  read_html() %>%  html_nodes('a') %>% 
    html_attr("href")` gets you all the links present in a given page.

Comment: @NadPat what is `remDr`?

Answer (score 1):

in their javascript you'll find the url `https://hazards-geoplatform.s3.amazonaws.com/` and there you'll find a xml file containing the path to (seemingly?) all their files, from there it shouldn't be hard, so

1: download the XML list of files from https://hazards-geoplatform.s3.amazonaws.com

2: each of the XML's `<content>` tag describes a file or a folder. filter out all the  tags that is not relevant to you, that means if the content->key tag does not contain the text `Brookings HYDA`, filter it out.

3: the remaining content tags contain your download path and save path, for every key tag that ends with `/`: this is a "folder", you can't download a fol6der, just create the path, for example if the key is

```
<Contents> 
    <Key>Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE/South_Dakota/60601300_BrookingsCO/Brookings HYDA/Hydraulics_DataCapture/Correspondence/</Key>
```

this means you should create the folders `Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE/South_Dakota/60601300_BrookingsCO/Brookings HYDA/Hydraulics_DataCapture/Correspondence` and move on, however if the key's value does *not* end with `/`, it means you should download it, for example if you find

```
<Contents>
    <Key>Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE/South_Dakota/60601300_BrookingsCO/Brookings HYDA/Hydraulics_DataCapture/Correspondence/200724-CityBrookings-AirportInfo_Email.pdf</Key>
    <LastModified>2022-03-04T17:54:48.000Z</LastModified>
    <ETag>"9fe9af393f043faaa8e368f324c8404a"</ETag>
    <Size>303737</Size>
    <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
</Contents>
```

it means the save filepath is `Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE/South_Dakota/60601300_BrookingsCO/Brookings HYDA/Hydraulics_DataCapture/Correspondence/200724-CityBrookings-AirportInfo_Email.pdf`
and the url to download the file is `https://hazards-geoplatform.s3.amazonaws.com/` + urlencode(key), in this case:
https://hazards-geoplatform.s3.amazonaws.com/Region8%2FR8_MIT%2FRisk_MAP%2FData%2FBLE%2FSouth_Dakota%2F60601300_BrookingsCO%2FBrookings%20HYDA%2FHydraulics_DataCapture%2FCorrespondence%2F200724-CityBrookings-AirportInfo_Email.pdf

idk how to do it with curl/r, but here's how to do it in PHP, happy porting

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
function curl_get(string $url): string
{
    echo "fetching {$url}\n";
    static $ch = null;
    if ($ch === null) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>1,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>0
        ));
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $ret = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)) {
        throw new Exception("curl error ".curl_errno($ch).": ".curl_error($ch));
    }
    return $ret;
}
$base_url = 'https://hazards-geoplatform.s3.amazonaws.com/';
$xml = curl_get($base_url);
$domd = new DOMDocument();
@($domd->loadHTML($xml));
$xp = new DOMXPath($domd);
foreach($xp->query("//key[contains(text(),'Brookings HYDA')]") as $node) {
    $relative = $node->nodeValue;
    if($relative[-1] === '/'){
         // it's a folder, ignore
        continue;
    }
    $dir = dirname($relative);
    if(!is_dir($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
    }
    $url = $base_url . urlencode($node->nodeValue);
    file_put_contents($relative, curl_get($url));
}
```

after running that for a few seconds i have

```
$ find
.
./fuk.php
./Region8
./Region8/R8_MIT
./Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP
./Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data
./Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE
./Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE/South_Dakota
./Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE/South_Dakota/60601300_BrookingsCO
./Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE/South_Dakota/60601300_BrookingsCO/Brookings HYDA
./Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE/South_Dakota/60601300_BrookingsCO/Brookings HYDA/Hydraulics_DataCapture
./Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE/South_Dakota/60601300_BrookingsCO/Brookings HYDA/Hydraulics_DataCapture/Correspondence
./Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE/South_Dakota/60601300_BrookingsCO/Brookings HYDA/Hydraulics_DataCapture/Correspondence/200724-CityBrookings-AirportInfo_Email.pdf
./Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE/South_Dakota/60601300_BrookingsCO/Brookings HYDA/Hydraulics_DataCapture/Correspondence/2D_Exceptions_2021Update.pdf
./Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE/South_Dakota/60601300_BrookingsCO/Brookings HYDA/Hydraulics_DataCapture/DCS_Checklist_Hydraulics_BrookingsCoSD.xlsx
./Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE/South_Dakota/60601300_BrookingsCO/Brookings HYDA/Hydraulics_DataCapture/Simulations
./Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE/South_Dakota/60601300_BrookingsCO/Brookings HYDA/Hydraulics_DataCapture/Simulations/RAS
./Region8/R8_MIT/Risk_MAP/Data/BLE/South_Dakota/60601300_BrookingsCO/Brookings HYDA/Hydraulics_DataCapture/Simulations/RAS/0.2PAC
```

soo it seems to be working.

- the last output from the command is

```
fetching https://hazards-geoplatform.s3.amazonaws.com/Region8%2FR8_MIT%2FRisk_MAP%2FData%2FBLE%2FSouth_Dakota%2F60601300_BrookingsCO%2FBrookings+HYDA%2FHydraulics_DataCapture%2FSimulations%2FRAS%2F0.2PAC%2FPostProcessing.hdf
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65019904 bytes) in /home/hans/test/fuk.php on line 17
```

meaning some of their files are over 134MB in size - it's easy to optimize the curl code to write directly to disk instead of storing the entire file in ram before writing to disk, but since you want to do this in R anyway, i won't bother optimizing the sample php script.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I do not know PHP well enough (don't know it at all actually) to convert this to R code.

Comment: @EricKrantz i just updated the post, trying to explain how to do it in a language-neutral way, check if that helps?

Comment: @EricKrantz also people in `ircs://irc.libera.chat:6697##Programming` / the programming support channel on [Libera Chat](https://libera.chat/) might be able to help you, if you're familiar with IRC (Libera also has a R and PHP support channel, called #R and #PHP )